# Using the VIM JavaScript syntax file

Tags: vim

I tried including the following syntax file into my vim.
I installed this plugin using Pathogen as per instruction:

```
git clone https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax.git ~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax
```

Then included the following in my .virc file

```
au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
```

After restarting vim and opening a JavaScript file I am not able to fold using the standard zo, zc commands .. any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the fold settings have been activated:

```
:verbose set foldmethod?
:syntax list foldBraces
```

The first should yield `syntax`, and the syntax group should be defined.

Note that only `{ ... }` blocks spanning multiple lines are folded by this.

Comment: The fist one yields syntax.. the second simply displays --- Syntax items ---

Comment: Hm, so the fold syntax group hasn't been defined. Does it work when you manually `:call JavaScriptFold()` again?

Comment: nothing happens .. any clue.. where I should start debugging ?

Comment: Does `:function JavaScriptFold` list the (3-line) function? You probably really need to step through the commands, either via `:debug`, or by capturing a log with `vim -V20vimlog`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may come across this scenario; I had the exact same problem.  The fix, for me, was to edit my .vimrc by moving

```
syntax enable
```

above

```
au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
```